# CommandbarControls.Move method for submenu

Tags: ms-access, vba, commandbar

Using the `Move` method of the `CommandBar` object I managed to move a `CommandBarControl` using the following syntax:

```
CommandBars("TopMenu").Controls("SomeControl").Move CommandBars("AnotherTopMenu")
```

I need, however, to move the control to a submenu (or popup menu) within a `CommandBar` and cannot find a way of doing it, as the first argument of the `Move` method will only accept a `CommandBar` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I subsequently found the answer [here](http://computer-programming-forum.com/1-vba/c10fea14f479a630.htm).

In a nutshell you need to use the `CommandBar` property of the popupmenu control.

```
CommandBars("AnotherTopMenu").Controls("PopupMenu").CommandBar
```